# Finding difference between 2 directories in linux

Tags: linux, shell

Hi guys,

```
      I was trying to find the difference between two directories, dir structure as follows.
```

1. dir1/subdir/file.txt
2. dir2/subdir/nffile.txt

when i tried with "diff -r dir1 dir2" it shows only the content difference in files but i want interns of new file addition.

Any possibility that we can find the difference between these dir using the "diff" command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try out using `--brief` option something like:

```
$ diff --recursive --brief dir1 dir2
Only in dir1/dir1: file1
Only in dir2/dir1: file2
Only in dir1: dir2
$
```

Answer (score 0):

Alt.1 - use of diff

```
diff <(ls dir1) <(ls dir2)
```

Alt.2 - script without use of diff

```
 for i in /my/directory/*; do
    name=$(basename "$i")
    if [[ ! -e "/my/other/directory/$name" ]]; then
       echo $name not found in other directory
    fi
 done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
diff -qrN dir1 dir2
```

if one of the directories has a name that can be confused with a paramenter

```
diff -qrN -- -f -z
```

where -f and -z are actually directory names

remove the `q` parameter to have more detail about what changed. If you want even more detail use the following

```
diff -rupN -- dir1 dir2
```

Answer (score 0):

### Quick and Dirty New Files Detection:

I was interested in finding the **new files created** after a install in a specific directory so I did the following:

1. Created a **hardlink mirror** of the directory of interest in its current structre state.

```
mkdir -p ~/tmp/snapshot/
cp -al ~/DirOfInterest/ ~/tmp/snapshot/
```

2. executed the install in `~/DirOfInterest/`
3. Used [the method as described in SMAs' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28979984/2078851)

```
diff -qr ~/DirOfInterest/ ~/tmp/snapshot/DirOfInterest/ &>~/ListOfNewFiles.txt
```

4. Once noted the differences, I deleted the "snapshot mirror"

```
rm -rf  ~/tmp/snapshot/DirOfInterest/
```

*Note: Since the "snapshot directory" is a mirror made of hardlinks, modifications to already existent files at the time of "snapshooting" across the installation procedure will not be detected since the hardlinks point to the same data blobs.* ***Only newly created Files*** *will be detected.*